# How to update the PMD and PTE tables of page-table by allocating or relocating memory?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, page-tables

I have a requirement of forcing the `PTE` and `PMD` levels of the *page-table* to be updated or in other words, to make the process **frequently** hold the `PMD` and `PTE` locks. This is for research purposes.

I know this could be done in one of two ways:

- Allocate a `MAP_ANONYMOUS` memory using `mmap`, touch the allocated memory (to allocate a physical memory), and then `munmap` it; both `mmap` and `munmap` update the *page-table*. But I don't know how to make this allocation/deallocation touch both tables.
- Allocate a memory using `mmap` like above, and frequently relocate the memory in such a way that modifies both `PMD` and `PTE` levels. For this, I couldn't find a way to move pages to a new location that causes both tables to be updated.

So my question is, how to allocate or relocate a mapped memory in such a way that both the `PTE` and `PMD` tables are updated? I presume any solution based on the above is a matter of finding a proper virtual address to map to or relocate to.

My processor is an *Intel Xeon Gold 6142* with 4 levels *page table*.